# C When declaring an array with values, is declaring the size useful?

Tags: arrays, c

When declaring an array in C, is there a difference between:

```c
int someNumbersArray[] = {10, 20, 30};
```

and:

```c
int someNumbersArray[3] = {10, 20, 30};
```

?

I suppose that the result is the same after compilation. Maybe the latter is slightly faster during compilation?

I tried the above code with an array of 10000 numbers and didn't see any difference.

PS:

- Declaring an array with too low size would cause issues (the compiler I use shows warning if so).
- I know you can declare an array with values, and give it a larger size; in this case obviously you actually have to declare the desired size.

Comment: If the size is smaller than the number of elements in the initializer, you'll probably get a compiler error...which is maybe a useful check?

Comment: This is not a purely opinion-based question.  As noted in @larsks's comment above, there are objective differences in the two different implementations.

Comment: @AndrewHenle computers are better in counting than humans

Comment: @gulpr And that's one objective difference.

Comment: Compilation speed is not a metric that C programmers often consider worthy of attention.  It's a little different for C++, but even there, any compilation speed difference you could reasonably expect for the two alternatives, even with many elements, whould typically be dwarfed by various considerations unique to C++.

Comment: Re "*is declaring the size useful?*", It's *harmful* under the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: "Maybe the latter is slightly faster during compilation?" I doubt so because either way the compiler has to count the identifiers and check so that there aren't too many. Either way, you should never let compilation speed be an argument for how you write C code.

Comment: If the dimension is tied to other parts of the program or bears special meaning, use a macro as the single source of truth and fill in the dimension using that macro. Otherwise just leave it empty so that the code keeps DRY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When declaring an array in C, is there a difference between [...]

The explicit array dimension in the second case being equal to the number of elements in the initializer, there is no *semantic* difference between the two alternatives presented.  They mean the same thing to C.

> Maybe the latter is slightly faster during compilation?

Perhaps, but you're unlikely to notice the difference, even for large numbers of elements and / or many such arrays.  Compilation speed is rarely a problem for C (as opposed to C++), so it's not a consideration that C programmers often think about.

What remains, then, is considerations revolving around code clarity and maintainability, development process, and similar.  Examples include,

- When a specific number of elements is important to the semantics of the program, such as for a vector in 3D space, explicitly declaring the size helps convey to other humans and to the compiler that exactly that number of elements is expected.  That can help both people and compilers to catch errors, and it provides a clue to other developers about what the array is for.
- On the other hand, if the importance of the array size is only that it be sufficient for whatever elements are presented, then omitting the explicit size tends to imply that.  In this case, omitting the size also helps the programmer avoid error, it is a bit easier to write, and it is easier to maintain when elements are added to or removed from the initializer.

  The canonical case on this side is probably declaring an array to hold a string initialized via a string literal.  It is a fairly common error for people to forget to declare enough space for the string terminator.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convenience. Imagine `int x[] = {1,5,4,5,78,3,4,5,67,3456,6,4,5,3,5,6,4,354,4,5,5,6,5,3,2,7,8,5,34,3,4,5,6,54,3,4,5,4,4};` It is quite hard to count the number in integers :)
2. You may want to declare an array longer than the number of the initializers (because you will need more elements later): `int x[30] = {1,2,3};`. The rest of the array will be initialized to `0`

> I suppose that the result is the same after compilation. Maybe the
> latter is slightly faster during compilation?

No there will not be any difference.

Comment: *No there will not be any difference.* There could be - good luck measuring it, though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Your comment is likely only to mislead.  If there is any difference in the performance, it is the same kind of difference that can arise almost anywhere in any program due to the vagaries of optimizing compilers and their long history of failing to recognize some pattern or isomorphism, or mutating the source code in an early pass such that later passes become worse (or better!).  You probably already know this, but your lack of explanation will make some readers think there could be an *intentional* or *universal* difference, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference to compiler but `int someNumbersArray[3] = {10, 20, 30};` checks if, as the coder, you provided more elements than needed/allowed to prevent a bug/misusage in cases you need exactly that amount of elements.

Still it can't check if you entered less elements.

Comment: A more compelling example might be `char alphabet[26] = { 'a', 'b', /* ... */, 'z' };`. Of course, the compiler can only check whether 26 letters were provided; it can't check for duplicates or other problems with data entry, so someone will still have to review the code manually.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is effectively no difference between the two declarations; if you don't specify a size, the array will be sized to accommodate the number of initializers.

One problem (as you've found) is if you do specify an array size but provide more elements in the initializer than the array is sized to hold:

```
int x[3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // problem
```

That's a constraint violation:

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> 2 No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being
> initialized.

<sup>*[C 202x Working Draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)*</sup>

Where things can get tricky is with *designated initializers*:

```
int x[] = { 0, 1, [9] = 2 };
```

This allocates `x` with 10 elements; it's equivalent to writing

```
int x[10] = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 };
```

If you specify an array size and provide fewer initializers than that size, any elements not explicitly initialized will be initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

> When declaring an array in C, is there a difference between...

No, if you match the number of initializers to the array size.  The value used between the brackets is used by the compiler to enforce the size, but if it is not provided, then the number of elements in the initializer list will be used.  Of course it is needed if you don't initialize the array in the declaration.

If the numbers don't match (the number of elements in the initializer, and the number in the brackets) then the number in the brackets takes precedence, and you will get only the number of initializers stated (if it is less than the array size) will be initialized, the rest being initialized to zero.  If the number between brackets is less (strictly less) you normally get a warning indicating that the *extra initializers* are being ignored by the compiler (and this can be a problem if you don't listen to the compiler warnings)